# jQuery set flash wmode parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am wondering if there is any jQuery plugin available to change the wmode to transparent at runtime. (Something similar to wibiya)

I tried googling, but could not find any exact plugin do to the job. The only resource I found was:

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/08/13/javascript_to_fix_wmode_parameters/
http://labs.kaliko.com/2009/11/change-wmode-with-jquery.html

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find a plugin for a relatively small amount of functionality like this; I think this snippet should just about cover it however:

```
$("object").append(
    $("<param/>").attr({
        'name': 'wmode',
        'value': 'transparent'
    })
).find("embed").attr('wmode', 'transparent')
```

I'm unsure when best to run it; `ready` might work yet I expect that may be too late as the flash content will have already been embedded? Worth experimenting with.