# Removing annotations on embedded YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube, embed

I've discovered that you can disable annotations on embedded YouTube videos by adding the parameter `&iv_load_policy=3` to the url in the embed code.

Example:

```
<object width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/PMnEvKCtHBw&hl=en&fs=1&iv_load_policy=3"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/PMnEvKCtHBw&hl=en&fs=1&iv_load_policy=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

Is there any way to force this parameter on all YouTube embed urls on a webpage using javascript/jQuery?

(Sort of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615742/jquery-set-flash-wmode-parameter/3631808#3631808) example where you force wmode transparent on all flash objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('object').each(function(){ 
        var $param = $(this).children(':first-child');
        var newUrl = $param.attr('value') + '&iv_load_policy=3';
        $param.attr('value', newUrl);
});
```

<del>Done quickly without testing....</del>

Tested and works

Comment: This solution does not seem to work anymore:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87kezJTpyMI&hd=1&iv_load_policy=3

Comment: Yes it should do, the link you posted was the URL for the video, not the embed URL. This only works with embedded videos.

Answer (score 0):

`iv_load_policy=3` is the way to go. However there are [nice embed code generator](http://online-marketing-technologies.com/tools/youtube-embed-code-generator.html)s, to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The new HTML5 player no longer uses this embed code, but I have just adapted this code to work with the iframe that is being embedded and have it working on my site. (Works with WordPress ombed too)

```
$("iframe").each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src") + '&iv_load_policy=3';
        $(this).attr("src", src);
});
```

Comment: I found out the hard way my code was targeting ALL iframes and breaking some things. Please use this new version which only targets youtube iframes. `$("iframe").each(function() {
  
 var isource = this.src;
          var src = $(this).attr("src") + '&iv_load_policy=3';
 
 if(isource.indexOf("youtu") >= 0){

          $(this).attr("src", src);
 }
 
    });`

Comment: If you use iFrame, when create YT.player, just pass playervars:
playerVars: {
                    'controls': 0,//no controls bar
                    'iv_load_policy': 3,//no annotations
                },