# Embedded YouTube Videos - Removing Videos at End

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

At the end of a YouTube video you will see other videos that you can choose to watch if you choose. I am embedding a YouTube video on my site and would prefer that those videos did not show at the end of the video. Is there a way to remove those videos and have just a reply option (or something similar). According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166846/removing-annotations-on-embedded-youtube-videos) you can remove the annotations from YouTube Videos that are embedded on your site and that made me wonder if the same can be achieved for end of video videos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes that is possible, use this script:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{link}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

The important part is the `?rel=0`.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of this changed on Sept. 25th 2018.

The behavior for the rel parameter is changing on or after September 25, 2018. The effect of the change is that you will not be able to disable related videos. However, you will have the option of specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from the same channel as the video that was just played.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#release_notes_08_23_2018